# I could not access to DynamicJasper maven repository

Tags: dynamic-jasper

What happen with this repo?

http://archiva.fdvs.com.ar/repository/public1/

I tried to use it yesterday and today but I could not

was migrated?

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could provide more information like: what error messages do you get when you're trying to access it?

Comment: Unable to determine IP address from host name for archiva.fdvs.com.ar

Comment: flas@SFU:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (200.40.0.80) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from cache.google.com (200.40.0.80): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=1.71 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.713/1.713/1.713/0.000 ms
flas@SFU:~$ ping archiva.fdvs.com.ar
ping: unknown host archiva.fdvs.com.ar
flas@SFU:~$

Comment: Related to 3rd party site. Off-topic

Answer (score 0):

The repo is up and running at the time of this post. It is the official repository URL for the project as clearly stated under http://dynamicjasper.com/download/.